# how to access UITextField in AppDelegate method

Tags: ios, uitextview, appdelegate

Hi I don't know how to access my UITextField from a AppDelegate method.

I have tried to add

```
@implementation TestAppDelegate

@synthesize textField;
```

But I still get an error. I just want to know if it's possible to access it from a AppDelegate method.

Comment: ... what error do you get?

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing anything like that in the AppDelegate.

Comment: If you put some effort in writing a better question, you can hope to get an answer and solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `UIViewController` class in your project, and you are using interface builder, and you want access your `UITextField` from AppDelegate, your project should look something like this:

MyViewController.h

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@end
```

MyAppDelegate.h

```
#include "MyViewController.h"
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

MyAppDelegate.m

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    MyViewController *viewController = (MyViewController *)[_window rootViewController];
    [[viewController textField] setText:@"It should work!"]
}
@end
```